# WPF Content of Control relative to source

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button, controls

I have the following code for a Custom WPF Radio Button that has an image as content.
The image Built Action is set to "Content" and the Copy to Output Directory to "Copy if newer".

```
<!--MaterialButtonTheme-->
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"
       x:Key="MaterialButtonTheme">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <Grid   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Border>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".3"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style.Setters>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".8"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".6"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Now, I don't want to use the hard code variant for the image resource, but the following does not work.

```
<RadioButton
                         x:Name="RadioButtonSteelMat"
                         Height="30" Width="30"
                         Foreground="White"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         FontSize="14"
                         Style="{StaticResource MaterialButtonTheme}"
                         Content="../EmbeddedResources/Images/steel.png"
                         IsChecked="False"
                         Margin="10,200,0,0" 
                         Checked="RadioButtonSteelMat_Checked"
                />
```

The following hard coded variant works just fine. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<RadioButton
                         x:Name="RadioButtonSteelMat"
                         Height="30" Width="30"
                         Foreground="White"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         FontSize="14"
                         Style="{StaticResource MaterialButtonTheme}"
                         Content="C:\Users\Niklas\Desktop\Studium\Master\M4\Thesis\Tool\OptioneeringTool\OptioneeringTool\B+GOpt\EmbeddedResources\Images\steel.png"
                         IsChecked="False"
                         Margin="10,200,0,0" 
                         Checked="RadioButtonSteelMat_Checked"
                />
```

Comment: In a WPF application you would typically set the Build Action of an image file to `Resource` and load it by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), e.g. `"pack://application:,,,/EmbeddedResources/Images/steel.png"`. You may have to use XAML element syntax to set the Content: `<RadioButton ...><BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/EmbeddedResources/Images/steel.png"/></RadioButton>`

Comment: Does it really have to be a png?  I'd far prefer a path. Or a drawingvisual if it absolutely must be multiple colours.  Material design is flat so I would have expected a path to work.

Comment: If you don't want to embed your image as a resource you can use `siteoforigin` instead of `application` pack uri. `"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/EmbeddedResources/Images/steel.png"` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#site-of-origin-pack-uris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Content="/EmbeddedResources/Images/steel.png"` should work assuming the EmbeddedResources folder is located at the root your project folder in Visual Studio when you build and that the `Built Action` of the image file is set to "Content" and the `Copy to Output Directory` property to "Copy if newer".

The other option is to set the `Built Action` to "Resource" and use a [pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) to reference it:

```
pack://application:,,,/EmbeddedResources/Images/steel.png
```